# JQuery function seems to update selector, but no items are displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a function within document that appears to be called and retrieval from the database appears to work (At this moment I only have 1 item in the database so I can't fully say it works).  I have it append to these selectors on the html page, but I see no updates.

Here is the following javascript:

```
function loadAddresses() {
$.ajax({
    url: "getAllAddresses.php",
    type: "get",
    datatype: "json",
        success: function(data) {
    if (data != null) {
        $('#addressEditSelector').empty();
        $('#addAddressSelector').empty();
        data.forEach(function(address) {
            var message = address.address1;
            if (address.address2 != null) message += " " + address.address2;
            message += " " + address.city + ", " + address.state;
            message += " " + address.zipcode;
            $('#addressEditSelector').append(message);
            $('#addAddressSelector').append(message);
        });
        }
    }   
});
}
$(document).ready(function() {

// load addresses ahead of time

loadAddresses();
    ...
}
```

I have the following selectors in the html file:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">Billing Address</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <select class="browser-default custom-select" id="addAddressSelector">
    </select>
</div>
</div>

...

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 text-right">Billing Address</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <select class="browser-default custom-select" id="addressEditSelector">
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

When using the javascript console I see the data from the database at the state: $('#addressEditSelector').append(message);

I've looked all over the webpage to find any conflicting IDs for either of them, but have had no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: You are not sending anything to the server. You either need to prepend a query string to the url (?item1=1&item2=2) or you need to specify `data` when you send the ajax call. We will need your php script also.

Comment: If you run `getAllAddresses.php` in your browser what result do you get? Please add to your question.

Comment: It adds all the addresses as JSON.  It works in other places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For text to be rendered inside a `<select>` you should put in an `<option>` tag.

Append the data using:

```
$('#addressEditSelector').append($('<option>').text(message));
$('#addAddressSelector').append($('<option>').text(message));
```

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) w3schools entry has more info about the `<select>` tag

Comment: Yea, I improved your answer.  $('#addressEditSelector').append($('<option>').text(message).val(address.id));
     $('#addAddressSelector').append($('<option>').text(message).val(address.id));